# A quick way to check the type of the drive

Tags: linux, storage, proc

Is there a quick way to understand a type of the "storage" on Linux? Is it a HDD or SSD (or NVMe)? 
It's already known that the host is a physical machine and not a VM.
The first thing I though about was `rotational` flag under `/sys/block/<device>/queue/` directory. But in my experience even for SSD devices it may contain "1" value.
The second way and more realistic and truthful was a latency.  It's a bit harder to measure (some work with /proc/diskstats), but looks more preferable.

Is there any other ways? It's important to mention that I don't need to know exact model of the "storage", just its type.

Comment: Measuring latency is not a good answer as some rotational disks come with huge caches which may or may not be easy to distinguish from full capacity solid state devices.

Comment: Along with `smartctl` mentioned here, other utilities such as `lshw` and `lsblk` report the same information. See also https://askubuntu.com/q/792814/295286

Comment: what would you use this info for? In other words, if I give you program called isHDDorSSD what will you do with it

Comment: Bonnie++ can show SSD vs HDD based on IOPS (as can dd)

Comment: @Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy, I've not found such info in `lshw`. Also `lsblk` relies on `rotational` flag in sysfs directory hence I can't trust it. `smartctl` uses ioctl call and asks inforamtion directly from device.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about something like `sudo smartctl -a /dev/<device> | grep Rotation` -- if this returns `Rotation Rate:   Solid State Device`, then that's an SSD. Not sure if this bullet-proof method, either.

Comment: Looks good, it works even with drives attached through RAID cards.

Comment: @lesovsky, I wouldn't count on it working through a RAID card.  I don't have any SSDs attached to RAID that I can test with, but it shows incorrect rotational rates for the spinning disks (every disk in the array shows up as 10k, when they're all actually 7.2k).